# Webscraping For Item In Stock

Tags: python, web-scraping

I had found some code actually on this site for webscraping a product that is in stock. I typed it out and fit it for my scenario, and all works great! Even got email notifications to work. However, when the item is out of stock, it has a "Out of stock" label on the product, and when the product is "In stock" that label isn't there. I don't know how to adjust the code yet to detect that when that "Out of stock" label isn't there.

No matter which stock option the send_mail() is attached too it will detect it being in stock (when it' actually out of stock) and sends me an email. So it's not actually detecting the product whether it's in stock or not.

Any ideas? Sorry if there is a lack of information (I will add that if needed) as this is my first post.

Here is the code:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    import time

    def get_page_html(url):
        headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
        like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"}
        page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        print(page.status_code)
        return page.content


    def check_item_in_stock(page_html):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')
        out_of_stock_divs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "stock available"})
        print(out_of_stock_divs)
        return len(out_of_stock_divs) != 0

    def check_inventory():
        url = "https://www.[redacted].com/hornady-5-56-nato-55-gr-fmj-m193-frontierr"
        page_html = get_page_html(url)
        if check_item_in_stock(page_html):
            print("In stock")
            send_mail()
        else:
            print("Out of stock")

    def send_mail():
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()

        server.login('email@email.com', 'password')

        subject = "Ammo Is In!"
        body = 'Check the link! https://www.[redacted].com/hornady-5-56-nato-55-gr-fmj-m193-frontierr'

        msg = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"

        server.sendmail(
            'email@email.com',
            'email2@email2.com',
            msg
        )
        print('Email has been sent')

        server.quit()


       while True:
        check_inventory()
        time.sleep(5)
```

I know it has something to do with the {"class": "stock available"}) field, but there is no stock available or div class when the item is in stock. So how can I write it that if it doesn't detect the "Out of stock" label, than it's actually in stock to send me an email?

I don't know how to incorporate an if statement with that def check_item_in_stock function.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make the function return False if the item is not in stock and the use that as a condition to send the mail. If check_inventory() returns False, send_mail() won't be called.

```
import smtplib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
def get_page_html(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    print(page.status_code)
    return page.content


def check_item_in_stock(page_html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')
    out_of_stock_divs = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "product-line-stock-msg-out-text"})
    if len(out_of_stock_divs) < 1:
        print("item is available")
        return True
    else:
        return False



def check_inventory():
    url = "https://www.rogerssportinggoods.com/Hornady-6mm-ARC-108Gr.-ELD-Match-20-rounds"
    page_html = get_page_html(url)
    while True:
        if check_item_in_stock(page_html) == True:
            send_mail()
        else:
            print("Item is out of stock")
            break


def send_mail():
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login('1243@gmail.com', 'psswd')
    subject = "Ammo Is In!"
    body = 'Check the link! https://www.rogerssportinggoods.com/Hornady-6mm-ARC-108Gr.-ELD-Match-20-rounds'
    msg = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"
    server.sendmail('1234@gmail.com','1234@gmail.com',msg)
    print('Email has been sent')

    server.quit()

check_inventory()
```

Comment: Thanks Abrar, I appreciate it! However when I run that code, it still show's item is in stock (item is currently out of stock still) and notifies me every 5 seconds. I did change the time.sleep(5) to 60 and the div class from stock available to product-line-stock to better match that item's div class. Here is the div class for that item that is currently out of stock.

<div class="product-line-stock">
    <p class="product-line-stock-msg-out">
    <span class="product-line-stock-icon-out"><i></i></span>
    <span class="product-line-stock-msg-out-text">Out of Stock</span></p>
</div>

Comment: Thanks Abrar! I edited the URL into the OP (It says it needs to be approved, so I'm not sure if you can see it yet). I wasn't sure if I'd get flagged or something for ammunition.

Comment: @TJStruck Works now. Check it.

Comment: I didn't realize you can also add the "span" even though it is under "div", so I thought since that was incorporated into the div class it would find it.

I appreciate your help on this. I will be examining the code to make sure I understand what you did better!

Comment: @TJStruck with `requests` as long as the element is not being generated dynamically, you can check for any element. Otherwise you have to use `selenium`. If an item is out of stock the page has to tell us so...so let us make that our `true` or `false` ..that is the simple logic.